# How do I choose a specific line from a file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make (as immature as this sounds) an application online that prints random insults.  I have a list that is 140 lines long, and I would like to print one entire line.  There is `mt_rand(min,max)` but when I use that alongside `fgets(file, "line")` It doesn't give me the line of the random number, it gives me the character.  Any help?  I have all the code so far below.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("Insults.txt","r");
echo fgets($file, (mt_rand(1, 140)));
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's easier version of what you want to do:

```
$file = file('Insults.txt');
echo $file[array_rand($file)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file("Insults.txt"); 
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

Or within a function:

```
function random_line($filename) { 
    $lines = file($filename) ; 
    return $lines[array_rand($lines)] ; 
}

$insult = random_line("Insults.txt"); 
echo $insult;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `file()` for this. it returns an array with the lines of the file:

```
$lines = file($filename);
$line = mt_rand(0, count($lines));   

echo $lines[$line];
```

Comment: why use mt_rand instead of array_rand?

Comment: because the op suggested it. Note that it provides *better* pseudo random numbers

Answer (score 0):

First: You totally screwed on using fgets() correctly, please refer to the manual about the meaning of the second parameter (it just plainly not what you think it is).

Second: the file() solution will work... until the filesize exceeds a certain size and exhaust the complete PHP memory. Keep in mind: file() reads the *complete* file into an array.

You might be better off with reading line-by-line, even if that means you'll have to discard most of the read data.

```
$fp = fopen(...);
$line = 129;

// read (and ignore) the first 128 lines in the file
$i = 1;
while ($i < $line) {
  fgets($fp); 
  $i++;
}
// at last: this is the line we wanted
$theLine = fgets($fp);
```

(not tested!)